# Are the elements present after a designator initializes elements in strictly increasing manner?

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, initializer-list, designated-initializer

Here, I have initialized array like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int a[10] = {1, 2, 3, [7] = 4, 8, 9};

    printf("a[7] = %d\na[8] = %d\na[9] = %d\n", a[7], a[8], a[9]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output :**

```
a[7] = 4
a[8] = 8
a[9] = 9
```

Here, I have selected array index `7` as a `a[7] = 4` and thereafter added some elements. Then print array elements of index `7`, `8` and `9` and print correctly.

So, Is it correct output of index `8` and `9` without explicitly defined it? 
Why sequence does not start from index `3`?

Comment: This is allowed in C99 (and gcc in C90): https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html; also see http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-declarations-initializations/184401377

Comment: Note it's not allowed in C++: yet another point on which the languages have diverged.

Comment: It might be allowed, but please don't do this very often, (never would be good:).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> *Why sequence does not start from index 3?*

because, that's not how it works!!

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9 for *designated initializer*  (*emphasis mine*)

> Each brace-enclosed initializer list has an associated current object. When no
>   designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according
>   to the type of the current object: array elements in increasing subscript order, structure
>   members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union.<sup>148)</sup> . In contrast, a
>   designation causes the following initializer to begin initialization of the subobject
>   described by the designator. **Initialization then continues forward in order, beginning
>   with the next subobject after that described by the designator.**<sup>149)</sup>

Thus, in your case, after the designator `[7]`, the remaining two elements in the brace enclosed list will be used to initialize the next sub-objects, array elements in index `8` and `9`.

Just to add a little more relevant info,

> If a designator has the form
>
> ```
> [ constant-expression ]
> ```
>
> then the current object (defined below) shall have array type and the expression shall be
>   an integer constant expression. [...]

Answer (score 6):

> Is it correct output of index 8 and 9 without explicitly defined it?

Yes, it is correct. Compiler will initialize elements of array after index `7`.
The initializer initializes the first three elements to `1`, `2` and `3`. Element at index `7` will have the value `4`. The two elements after index `7` will have values `8` and `9` respectively.

> Why sequence does not start from index 3?

Designated initializer `[7]` tells the compiler to continue the initialization of array elements after index `7`.